# Improve my code: Regex parse a comma separated numeric list

Tags: c#, regex

This code in LinqPad outputs a string of numbers in the Regex:

```
void Main()
{
    string a = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7";
    var myList = Regex.Match(a, @"^\s*((\d+)\s*,?\s*)+\s*$")
        .Groups[2].Captures.ToList();
    myList.Dump();
}

public static class EM
{
    public static List<string> ToList( this CaptureCollection value)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach( var item in value)
        {
            result.Add( ((Capture) item).Value );
        }
    return result;
    }
}
```

It works but my main focus is simply to put only the numbers in a string array using the Regex.  Is there something short and sweet to accomplish the same thing?

Edit:

I'm using Regex because I need to parse something like this:

```
string a = "deptid = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7";
var myList = Regex.Match(a, 
             @"^\s*(?<field>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*(?<op>==?)\s*((\d+)\s*,?\s*)+\s*$")
             .Groups[2].Captures.ToList();
```

Comment: In response to edit: then use `Split` on `=` then `Split` on `,` after that.

Comment: +1 with what @Timothy Shields said.

Comment: Can you show some of your sample xml text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of writing this code in Regex, Why don't you try to use `LINQ`?

try this one:

```
List<string> yourList = a.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToList();
```

But if you want to stick with array, then use this:

```
var yourList = a.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
```